# stacked column chart for two data sets - Google Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization, stacked

I'm generating some Google Charts and I'm stuck here. Google allows you to have your columns stacked. But it's either limited or I can't configure it to work. Taken from Google, here is an example showing number of cups of coffee produced in each year for two countries:

[image: number of cups of BEAN COFFEE per year for Austria and Belgium]

Say I have another data set for the same two countries, but this time I have instant coffee instead of ground. Example:

[image: number of cups of INSTANT COFFEE per year for Austria and Belgium]

What I'd like to do is to stack these two datasets on top of each other. So each column would be a single country, but two divisions: bean and instant coffee.

I was thinking if there was a way of formatting the data table in the following way:

```
['Year', 'Austria', 'Austria (instant)', 'Bulgaria', 'Bulgaria (instant')],
['2003', 1736060, 10051, 250361, 68564],
['2004', 1338156, 65161, 786849, 1854654],
['2005', 1276579, 65451, 120514, 654654]
```

to generate something like

[image]

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you may use Combo chart https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart,

Comment: I don't know how that does the job?

Comment: Hi, have look at here https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/bar_charts, here in the Chart Types , check with the bvo chart type, it could help you more

Comment: @jothikannan, that may work, but only in the Image charts, not the interactive charts.

Comment: even though it might work with the image charts, you can see it says "deprecated" on the page, so maybe not provided by Google anymore.

Comment: I have four column in the chart but I want to stacked only two columns, how to do?

Comment: It's super hacky, but this guy has done it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490942/column-stacked-chart-by-groups

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue today and followed your submission link. It seems that just recently someone replied with this:

> "This is actually possible with the new Material Bar chart (albeit in
>   a somewhat roundabout way). In the new chart, if you make a chart
>   stacked, but place some series on a different axis, that creates a
>   separate stack for those series. Unfortunately, there is currently no
>   way to completely hide an axis yet, and you will have to explicitly
>   set the view window. Eventually we will introduce options to hide axes
>   and to align view windows, but this will have to do for now."

This fiddle seemed to help me solve this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/p7o0pjgg/

Here's the code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
    'packages': ['bar']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Instant');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Instant');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Beans');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Beans');
    data.addRows([
        ['2001', 321, 621, 816, 319],
        ['2002', 163, 231, 539, 594],
        ['2003', 125, 819, 123, 578],
        ['2004', 197, 536, 613, 298]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        chart: {
            title: 'Year-by-year coffee consumption',
            subtitle: 'This data is not real'
        },
        vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0,
                max: 1000
            }
        },
        series: {
            2: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
            3: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            }
        }
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

Comment: I actually saw your answer just now ;) just because I had moved away from that requirement quite a while ago and didn't realise there was a new answer to it from more than a year ago! But the fiddle is proof enough that it actually is the solution. thanks

Comment: Is it still possible with latest revision of the library? Code above won't work with current version

Comment: @Julien I believe it still works in principle. The JSFiddle example provided may have a minor bug preventing it from working. See my answer below for a working copy.

Comment: I have a feeling that does not work for Combi charts. I have taken the fiddle from Google Chart documentation and added `targetAxisIndex`: [it does not work](https://jsfiddle.net/dma_k/e4qy4o9r/). Have I missed something?

Comment: What steps to follow to add annotations to the above chart?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using a `stacked column chart`, where all data series of one group (e.g. ground coffee) is on the left axis, and all data series of the other group on the right axis (instant coffee).

**data and stacked column chart set-up**

[image]

**series of group 2 moved to right axis**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Visualization API does not support creating multiple column stacks per row of data.  You can make a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support for this if you want.

Comment: thanks mate, just submitted a feature request. It will be so cool if they actually add that.

Comment: here's the link to the request: [multiple stacked bar charts](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1270&q=multiple%20stacked%20bar%20charts&sort=owner&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Comment: I have four column in the chart but I want to stacked only two columns, how to do?

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Dan Hogan worked for me. However, the JSFiddle example didn't seem to work (not sure, why.) Here is a version that works for me.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $('.service-usage-graph').each(function() {

        var table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        table.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        table.addColumn('number', 'UL Peak');
        table.addColumn('number', 'UL Off-peak');
        table.addColumn('number', 'DL Peak');
        table.addColumn('number', 'DL Off-peak');

        table.addRow(['2001-01-01', 1, 2, 3, 4]);
        table.addRow(['2001-01-03', 3, 2, 4, 2]);
        table.addRow(['2001-01-04', 2, 2, 4, 2]);
        table.addRow(['2001-01-05', 0, 1, 4, 5]);
        table.addRow(['2001-01-06', 9, 2, 6, 8]);
        table.addRow(['2001-01-07', 2, 2, 7, 3]);
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(this);
        var options = google.charts.Bar.convertOptions({
            isStacked: true,
            series: {
                2: { targetAxisIndex: 1 },
                3: { targetAxisIndex: 1 }
            },
            vAxis: {
              viewWindow: {
                max: 15,
              }   
            }   
        });
        chart.draw(table, options);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="service-usage-graph"></div>
```

Comment: I have four column in the chart but I want to stacked only two columns, how to do?

Comment: Is there a way to add annotations in the above chart?