# Legend position not working in stacked column charts (Google Charts)

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm making multiple stacked charts with Google Charts just like what was talking about in this post [stacked column chart for two data sets - Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925722/stacked-column-chart-for-two-data-sets-google-charts). I'm trying the sample but I can't set  the legend position with `legend: {position: 'top'}`.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7o0pjgg/32/

Comment: I'm commenting from my tablet so I don't have full developer tools to help troubleshoot, but I don't see the convertOptions() method listed for google.visualization.Bar in the api specs on developers.google.com/charts/ .  Probably getting undefined there and then the chart uses default options.  Just pass it your options object directly.

Comment: You need convertoptions for the stacked bars, what do you mean exactly with "pass it your options object directly" ? Could you adjust the jsfiddle with a working solution please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the list of options that **don't work** in *Material* charts can be found here...

[Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

which includes...

`legend.position: ['top', 'bottom']`

Comment: I have four column in the chart but I want to stacked only two columns, how to do?

Comment: @Rana check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405896/5090771)...

Comment: is it possible to add isStacked: true, only for last two columns of four columns chart.

Comment: yes, in the example given in previous comment, use chart option `targetAxisIndex` to control which columns are stacked, or not...