# Transparent background with multiple stacked google.charts.Bar,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I need to do multiple stacked bar/column chart with transparent background.

So, transparent background can be obtain pretty easily via:

```
var data = //my data
var options = {
    backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'}
} 

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnChart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

This works perfectly when I use `google.visualization` API.

What is more I need to do multiple stacked chart like in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7o0pjgg/).

Again this work perfecty BUT we need to use `google.charts` API there.

When we try to add `backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'}` to given jsfiddle our background wont be 100% transparent - chart area will still be white.

On the other hand we cannot implement a multistacked chart in `google.visulatization` API as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17932627/3804906).

So my question is:

How to combine those two features? What is more I want to hide right axes and their ticks/lines and rescale it to fit left axis

Comment: You Cane do this with canvas

Comment: @AnilSamal any example?

Comment: @AnilSamal maybe this will work but u are not using google charts anymore :/ I asking for google chart solution first - if there is not then I will think about changing lib

Comment: ok let me try  google chart once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to --> `backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'}`

you can set the background color of the chart area with...

```
    chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawStuff,
    packages:['bar']
});

function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Instant');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Instant');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Beans');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Beans');
    data.addRows([
        ['2001', 321, 621, 816, 319],
        ['2002', 163, 231, 539, 594],
        ['2003', 125, 819, 123, 578],
        ['2004', 197, 536, 613, 298]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        chart: {
            title: 'Year-by-year coffee consumption',
            subtitle: 'This data is not real'
        },
        vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0,
                max: 1000
            }
        },
        series: {
            2: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
            3: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            }
        },
        backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
        chartArea: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div style="background-color: magenta;">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

---

**note:**

recommend using `loader.js` to load the library, instead of `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will *only* change the `load` statement

`google.charts.load('current', {packages:['bar']});`

you can also include the `callback` in the `load` statement, as in the above snippet...